# Sorting 2 letter strings in array that contains only 3 letters with linear time algorithm

Tags: c#, arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

I have 2 letter strings that can contain only 3 characters: `X`,`Y`,`Z` and I have to sort them linear time, any suggestions?

for example:

```
string[] arr = new string[] { "XY", "XX", "ZY", "ZX" };
```

and I have to sort this array using linear time algorithm.

Comment: You can try *radix sort* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort, *bucket sort* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort

Comment: Are duplicates possible?

Comment: but is there maybe faster method than radix sort?

Comment: yes, they are possible

Comment: There are only, what, 9 possible values here? 9 counters (or an array) can store how many instances of each you've seen and then you just enumerate those counters in the fixed order.

Comment: @Inf: you can't have a method faster then `O(n)` - you have to read each item at least once, radix sort is `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

There are only 3^2=9 possible Strings, so you can use an int[9]-array in which you count how often each String appears. (takes O(n) time)

Than interate the int-array and output the sorted list (takes  O(n) time)

---

To map a Sting to its index of the array treat it as a number base 3 where

```
X=0  
Y=1
Z=2
```

example:

```
"XY" -> 01(base3) = 0*3 + 1*1 = 1 => index= 1
"ZX" -> 21(base3) = 2*3 + 1*1 = 7 => index= 7
```